# How to check the file exist in checklistbox using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am using checkListbox to select multiple files for a process.I want know how to check the selected file is exists with the content. Let me know. Thanks in advance.

My code is :

```
Dim FILE_NAME As String
For j = 0 To chkListBox.Items.Count - 1
    If Not chkListBox.Items(j) = "Select/UnselectAll" Then
        If chkListBox.GetItemChecked(j) = True Then
            FILE_NAME = chkListBox.Items(j)
        End If
    End If
Next
If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
    Timer1.Start()
Else
    MessageBox.Show("File Does Not Exist..... Please select any File")
    btnFileSelection.Focus()
End If
```

Here the condition works correctly when I select no files. But if i select single file in the list means the "File doesn't exist" Message Box displaying till the loop exist. How to Solve it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537952/check-if-an-item-is-already-exist-in-listbox1

Comment: @KeertiSystematixInfotech I want to check the checklistbox files are in checked state. If anyone of the files checked means my process should run or else i want show an message. Thank you

Comment: Please check answer given below.

Answer (score 0):

```
If chkListBox.CheckedItems.Count > 0 Then
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
    Timer1.Start()
Else
    MessageBox.Show("File Does Not Exist..... Please select any File")
    btnFileSelection.Focus()
End If
```

Comment: If this answer is useful for you, please mark it as answer.